# Apache Drill Query PostgreSQL Json

Tags: json, postgresql, apache-drill

I am trying to query a jsonb field in PostgreSQL in drill and read it as if were coming from a json storage type but am running into trouble. I can conver from text to json but cannot seem to query the json object. At least I think I can convert to JSON. My goal is to avoid reading through millions of uneven json objects from PostgreSQL, perform joins and things with text files such as CSV files and XML files. Is there a way to query the text field as if it were coming from a json storage type without writing large files to disk?

The goal is to generate results implicitly which PostgreSQL nor Pentaho do and integrate these data sets with others of any format.

Attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT convert_to(json_field,'JSON') as data FROM postgres.mytable) as q1
```

Sample Result:

```
[B@7106dd
```

Attempt to existing field that should be in any json object:

```
  SELECT data[field] FROM (SELECT convert_to(json_field,'JSON') as data FROM postgres.mytable) as q1
```

Result:

```
   null
```

Attempting to do anything with jsonb results in a Null Pointer Error.

Comment: Hi Andrew How are you connecting to Postgresql  ? Eg ODBC or JDBC

Comment: My connection is through the JDBC driver.

Comment: @AndrewScottEvans I am getting null when i select jsonb column in Apache drill..is there any specific configuration setting?